# How to modify href property on Leaflet 1.8 Popup?

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

Is there a way to modify the href property of the close button on a Leaflet 1.8 popup? I can’t find anything in the documentation for it.

Comment: What type of value would you like it to be?

Comment: See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/8159

Comment: @ghybs I want to disable the href altogether. I just want the Close button to close the popup. I use a Hash Router in a Single Page Application and it breaks my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is indeed no API in Leaflet for that specifically.

However you can easily customize Leaflet behaviour by modifying how its classes behave.

In your case, you would override [`L.Popup._initLayout` method](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.8.0/src/layer/Popup.js#L183).

Something like:

```
L.Popup.include({
  _originalInitLayout: L.Popup.prototype._initLayout, // Keep a reference to super method

  _initLayout() {
    this._originalInitLayout();
    this._closeButton?.href = "#myCustomValue"; // Change the value as desired
  }
});
```

See also the [Leaflet tutorial about extending its classes](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html).